# change urlparse.path of a url

Tags: python, python-3.x, urlparse

Here is the python code:

```
url = http://www.phonebook.com.pk/dynamic/search.aspx
path = urlparse(url)
print (path)

>>>ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.phonebook.com.pk', path='/dynamic/search.aspx', params='', query='searchtype=cat&class_id=4520&page=1', fragment='')

print (path.path)
>>>/dynamic/search.aspx
```

Now I need to change the `path.path` to my requirement. Like if "/dynamic/search.aspx" is the path then I only need the parts between the first slash and last slash including slashes which is "/dynamic/".

I have tried these two lines but end result is not what I expected that's why I am asking this question as my knowledge of "urllib.parse" is insufficient.

```
path = path.path[:path.path.index("/")]
print (path)
>>>Returns nothing.
path = path.path[path.path.index("/"):]
>>>/dynamic/search.aspx (as it was before, no change.)
```

In short whatever the path.path result is my need is directory names only. For example:" dynamic/search/search.aspx". now I need "dynamic/search/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to look into `urlparse` to find any method that could help in your situation, but didn't find, may be overlooked, but anyway, at this level, you probably would have to make your own method or hack:

```
>>> path.path
'/dynamic/search.aspx'

>>> import re
>>> d = re.search(r'/.*/', path.path)
>>> d.group(0)
'/dynamic/'
```

This is just an example to you, you may also use built-in methods, like so:

```
>>> i = path.path.index('/', 1)
>>> 
>>> path.path[:i+1]
'/dynamic/'
```

EDIT:

I didn't notice your last example, so here is another way:

```
>>> import os
>>> path = os.path.dirname(path.path) + os.sep
>>> path
'/dynamic/'
>>> path = os.path.dirname(s) + os.sep
>>> path
'dynamic/search/'
```

Or with `re`:

```
>>> s
'dynamic/search/search.aspx'
>>> d = re.search(r'.*/', s)
>>> d
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 15), match='dynamic/search/'>
>>> d.group(0)
'dynamic/search/'
>>> 
>>> s = '/dynamic/search.aspx'
>>> d = re.search(r'.*/', s)
>>> d.group(0)
'/dynamic/'
```

Answer (score 12):

First, the desired part of the `path` can be obtained using `rfind` which returns the index of the last occurrence. The `+ 1` is for keeping the trailing slash.

```
desired_path = path.path[:path.path.rfind("/") + 1]
```

Second, use the `_replace` method to replace the `path` attribute of the `urlparse` object as follows:

```
desired_url = urlunparse(path._replace(path=desired_path))
```

The full working example:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse

url = "http://www.phonebook.com.pk/dynamic/search/search.aspx"
path = urlparse(url)

desired_path = path.path[:path.path.rfind("/") + 1]
desired_url = urlunparse(path._replace(path=desired_path))
```

Comment: `_replace` looks like a private API that could disappear without warning :(

Comment: @mgalgs I agree it is not ideal. But by setting the Python version, you also freeze the urllib version. A controlled environments should avoid a code break if the method changes.

Comment: No, `_replace` is not a private API (even though it seriously looks like one...) it's just underscored so it doesn't collide with field names on the namedtuple.

Comment: `_replace` is mentioned in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#structured-parse-results So it's not going away any time soon.